# Is there a way to call different http-requests from one method several times until we get the answer?

Tags: c#, httprequest

I have webAPI from one web-service which wrapped in C#-methods (library).
As http-requests (GET) they can return error for the first time they called, but return answer on the second or third time.

So I want to make some method which will call any passed method with parameters and will try to get answer several times.

Something like this:

```
        bool trySuccess = false;
        int tryCount = 0;
        while (trySuccess == false && tryCount < 6)
        {
            try
            {
                newEvents = webAPI.GetNewEvents(authToken, uniqueId);
                trySuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log("fail", tryCount);
            }
            tryCount++;
        }
```

Is there solution or each call should be wrapped on its own?

Comment: `Something like this` Did you try that code? Did it work?

Comment: [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) is a pretty good library for dealing with transient faults.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, I was looking for something universal. Thanks to the answer about retry pattern I wrote "Retry" class with delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly), a fantastic library for handling transient faults, you could replace all your code with something like this:

```
var newEvent = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
                     .Retry(6)
                     .Execute(() => webAPI.GetNewEvents(authToken, uniqueId));
```

(This may not be 100% correct, as I don't have Visual Studio available for testing it right now, but it should be close enough to get you where you need to go.)

If you still want your logging message written on failures, it would look like this:

```
var newEvent = Policy.Handle<Exception>((exception, retryCount, context) => 
                                        Log("fail", retryCount))
                     .Retry(6)
                     .Execute(() => webAPI.GetNewEvents(authToken, uniqueId));
```

Comment: I think that this is fantastic and really good way to handle this. I wrote my own class for current project, but I think that this is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look the Retry Pattern, it fits what you want:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/retry

Comment: Yes, it fits! Thank you I used it to write my own class to handle retries.